# Unexpected shutdown

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

So I am new to Ubuntu, and have installed 12.04 LTS version. The only problem I have until now, are unexpected shutdowns.

When it happens, it pops up for one second a black screen with sth written on it and then shut down. **I think it is because of overheating**. I try, on purpose, runned as many programs as possible, to make it shut down again, I also prepared the camera to take a photo of the quick message. I was also checking temperature, via command "sensors" in terminal. Last check before shutdown was 84°C (critical is 86).

I don't know how to attach image here, so I have written error below:

```
*Checking battery state...
Broadcast message from root@ubuntu
      (unknown) at 11:46 ...
The system is going down for power off NOW!
acpid: exiting
Checking for running anattended-upgrades:
      speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
```

It is strange, because I have never had unexpected errors in Windows 7. On Ubuntu it is happening all the time.

Computer:

- Medion,
- AkoyaP6630 2.66Ghz,
- 4GB RAM )

Comment: If it’s not the hardware problem, Ubuntu may have problems with your BIOS settings and thus doesn’t have a proper control on the fan.

Answer (score 1):

This has occurred to me too. 84 C is the temperature at which Ubuntu automatically shutdowns to avoid causing further damage to your computer. Trust me, my old laptop died because of this overheating occurring too many times. so try to find out why it is overheating. Check whether the fans of your system are operating properly. 84 C is a very high temperature for a CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same thing happened with me on ubuntu 12.04...The solution is nothing but to open your CPU (if possible ;) ) and clean the dust. The fan which sits above your processor is very important so clean it properly and it will solve your problem(just make sure you don't damage your motherboard)..

Note:To check temperature of your CPU use BIOS(hardware monitor) because if there is some problem with your OS then you will come to know about that from BIOS..

hope this helps!